# Couldn't read row and column from CursorWindow

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm trying to fill in a two-dimensional array, with data from my DB SQLite. But the following happens:

It's my first time with SQLite, by the way, and I was trying to find out if there was something like a "Result Set" or a "Data Table" ... and I found the so-called "Cursor". Ok, I started using it ... inserting a single row in each table (all normal) but now when I insert another row in my subject table, the application crashes when I try to navigate in the cursor.

> E/CursorWindow: Failed to read row 6, column 6 from a CursorWindow which has 12 rows, 6 columns.

My table is only made up of 6 columns, and as for the data, the same application shows me that it has 2 rows, but for some reason it only reads the data from the first row and the other rows not.

```
public String[][] getMaterias(){
    String[][] materias = new String[rows][6];
    Cursor cursor = admin.selectLog(DBScheme.Tabla_Materias);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    try {
        for(int f = 0; f < rows; f++){
            for(int c = 0; c < 6; c++){
                materias[f][c] = cursor.getString(cursor.getPosition());
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }
    }catch (IllegalStateException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return materias;
}
```

I doubt very much that I have to do something like change the version of the database, since I have not touched the schema of the DB, only the only thing I have done was add another row of data. How I can solve this guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> E/CursorWindow: Failed to read row 6, column 6 from a CursorWindow
>   which has 12 rows, 6 columns.

The above message is quite explantory, but you need to think in terms of offsets. That is you have a Cursor with 12 rows and 6 columns (*from a CursorWindow which has 12 rows, 6 columns*).

That means that you can use offsets **0** to **5** for the columns and that there is no column 6 (offset).

Using position as the column index, as per `materias[f][c] = cursor.getString(cursor.getPosition());` will always result in such an error if the number of rows in the cursor exceeds the number of columns in the table.

You may wish to consider the following as not only a fix for the issue but also as perhaps a more adaptable solution (i.e there is no reliance on fixed/hard coded numbers as the number of rows and the number of columns is determined according to the Cursor)

```
public String[][] getMaterias(){
    Cursor cursor = admin.selectLog(DBScheme.Tabla_Materias);
    String[][] materias = new String[cursor.getCount()][cursor.getColumnCount()];

    while(cursor.moveToNext())
        for(int c = 0; c < cursor.getColumnCount(); c++){
            materias[cursor.getPosition()][c] = cursor.getString(c);
        }
    }
    return materias;
}
```

Perhaps even consider making it even more generic by passing a cursor (any cursor) as per :-

```
public String[][] getMaterias(Cursor cursor){
    String[][] materias = new String[cursor.getCount()][cursor.getColumnCount()];

    while(cursor.moveToNext())
        for(int c = 0; c < cursor.getColumnCount(); c++){
            materias[cursor.getPosition()][c] = cursor.getString(c);
        }
    }
    return materias;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I feel very embarrassed to ask something really stupid ... the solution was in my eyes all this time:

I just had to change *cursor.getPosition()* with the *c* variable:

```
 for(int f = 0; f < rows; f++){
            for(int c = 0; c < 6; c++){
                materias[f][c] = cursor.getString(c);
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }
```

I´m really sooorry....